# setxkbmap reverts after typing on second keyboard

Tags: linux

I am running Manjaro-i3 linux.  My setup is two keyboards, one built into my laptop, and another usb.  They are both qwerty keyboards.  I would like it so that the one built into my laptop types in qwerty, and the usb one types in dvorak.  In order to do this, I run this command:

```
setxkbmap -device 11 dvorak
```

Running this command makes my usb keyboard type dvorak, but as soon as I type something on my primary keyboard(that is typing qwerty), my usb keyboard reverts to qwerty.  How can I make it so that it does not revert??